# Restrict YouTube recommendations to some language(s)

Tags: youtube, localization

Is there any way I could restrict YouTube recommendations to just English, or better, English and some other languages too?

My three years old loves watching cartoons on YouTube. He does not type much but instead follows recommendations a lot, so often times I find him watching cartoons in Japanese or French which does not help him with grasping the language.

Any thoughts?